# Laravel 5.0 auth controller indefinite redirect loop

Tags: php, html, laravel, authentication, redirect

I recently tried to change my

```
Route::controllers([
  'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
]);
```

to

```
Route::controllers([
  '/' => 'Auth\AuthController',
]);
```

however, I noticed that this puts the entire site into a perminant redirect loop to a single page when one logs in(if one logs out, the problem disappears).  Can anyone explain to me why this is and how to get around this?  I would like the auth routes in the root rather in `auth/` if possible.

NOTE: The welcome and home controllers are both commented out so they cannot conflict.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem to be the ordering of routes.  When I pulled up the route list, I noticed that the routes for auth included `login/`, `logout/` and `{_missing}`.  The `{_missing}` route was intercepting every other route call since it was declared before all of my other routes.  Thus, since the `{_missing}` route uses the guest middleware, it redirected to the home.